# Integrate Outlook "Run as Script" rule into Excel VBA code that sends email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have an Excel VBA script that creates a **`pdf`** of the active worksheet and then sends an email with Outlook with the **`pdf`** attached.

Then I have a rule in Outlook that runs a script on Emails that arrive in the Sent folder based on keywords in the subject that saves a **`pdf`** copy of that email and/or it's attachments.

I would rather just have the Excel VBA script save that **`pdf`** copy of the email that was just sent by the excel vba script.  Otherwise, I would need to implement the Outlook "run as script" rule on every computer in our system.

**How can I marry the Outlook script with the Excel script??**

**Excel Code to send email (works fine):**

```
Sub AttachActiveSheetPDF_01()
  Dim IsCreated As Boolean
  Dim PdfFile As String, Title As String
  Dim OutlApp As Object

   ' Define PDF filename
  Title = Range("C218").Value
  PdfFile = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\" & Title & ".pdf"


  ' Exportactivesheet as PDF
  With ActiveSheet
    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=PdfFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
  End With

  ' Use already open Outlook if possible
  On Error Resume Next
  Set OutlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
  If Err Then
    Set OutlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    IsCreated = True
  End If
  OutlApp.Visible = True
  On Error GoTo 0

  ' Prepare e-mail with PDF attachment
  With OutlApp.CreateItem(0)

    ' Prepare e-mail
    .Subject = Title
    .To = "" ' <-- Put email of the recipient here
    .CC = "" ' <-- Put email of 'copy to' recipient here
    .Body = "Hello," & vbLf & vbLf _
          & "Please find attached a completed case review." & vbLf & vbLf _
          & "Thank you," & vbLf _
          & Application.UserName & vbLf & vbLf
    .Attachments.Add PdfFile

    ' Try to send
    Application.Visible = True
    .Display
  End With

  ' Quit Outlook if it was not already open
  If IsCreated Then OutlApp.Quit

  ' Release the memory of object variable
  Set OutlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Outlook script to save pdf copy of email (works fine):**

```
Function CleanFileName(strText As String) As String
Dim strStripChars As String
Dim intLen As Integer
Dim i As Integer
strStripChars = "/\[]:=," & Chr(34)
intLen = Len(strStripChars)
strText = Trim(strText)
For i = 1 To intLen
strText = Replace(strText, Mid(strStripChars, i, 1), "")
Next
CleanFileName = strText
End Function



Sub SaveAsPDF(MyMail As MailItem)
' ### Requires reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime ###
' ### Requires reference to Microsoft Word Object Library ###
' --- In VBE click TOOLS > REFERENCES and check the boxes for both of the above ---
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim strSubject As String
Dim strSaveName As String
Dim blnOverwrite As Boolean
Dim strFolderPath As String
Dim sendEmailAddr As String
Dim senderName As String
Dim looper As Integer
Dim plooper As Integer
Dim strID As String
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem

strID = MyMail.EntryID
Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oMail = olNS.GetItemFromID(strID)

' ### Get username portion of sender email address ###
sendEmailAddr = oMail.SenderEmailAddress
senderName = Left(sendEmailAddr, InStr(sendEmailAddr, "@") - 1)

' ### USER OPTIONS ###
blnOverwrite = False ' False = don't overwrite, True = do overwrite

' ### Path to save directory ###
bPath = "Z:\email\"

' ### Create Directory if it doesnt exist ###
If Dir(bPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
    MkDir bPath
End If

' ### Get Email subject & set name to be saved as ###
emailSubject = CleanFileName(oMail.Subject)
saveName = Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd-hhmm") & "_" & emailSubject & ".mht"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' ### Increment filename if it already exists ###
If blnOverwrite = False Then
    looper = 0
    Do While fso.FileExists(bPath & saveName)
        looper = looper + 1
        saveName = Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd-hhmm") & "_" & senderName & "_" & emailSubject & "_" & looper & ".mht"
        Loop
Else
End If

' ### Save .mht file to create pdf from Word ###
oMail.SaveAs bPath & saveName, olMHTML
pdfSave = bPath & Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd-hhmm") & "_" & senderName & "_" & emailSubject & ".pdf"
If fso.FileExists(pdfSave) Then
    plooper = 0
    Do While fso.FileExists(pdfSave)
    plooper = plooper + 1
    pdfSave = bPath & Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd-hhmm") & "_" & senderName & "_" & emailSubject & "_" & plooper & 

".pdf"
    Loop
Else
End If


' ### Open Word to convert .mht file to PDF ###
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

' ### Open .mht file we just saved and export as PDF ###
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=bPath & saveName, Visible:=True)
wrdApp.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
            pdfSave, ExportFormat:= _
            wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
            wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=0, To:=0, _
            Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
            CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
            BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False

wrdDoc.Close
wrdApp.Quit

' ### Delete .mht file ###
Kill bPath & saveName

' ### Uncomment this section to save attachments ###
'If oMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
'    For Each atmt In oMail.Attachments
'        atmtName = CleanFileName(atmt.FileName)
'        atmtSave = bPath & Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd-hhmm") & "_" & atmtName
'        atmt.SaveAsFile atmtSave
'    Next
'End If

Set oMail = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be hard to change your [outlook-vba](/questions/tagged/outlook-vba) to [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba), just move your outlook script to Excel Module and modify the following line.

```
Set App = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") '<- add
Set olNS = App.GetNamespace("MAPI") '<- change
```

Now create new Module and add the following code

```
Option Explicit
Sub Outlook()
    Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olItem As Object

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = olNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
    Set olItem = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    For Each olItem In olFolder.Items
        If olItem.Class = olMail Then
            If olItem.Subject = [A1] Then '< - update cell range
                Debug.Print olItem
                SaveAsPDF olItem '< - Call SaveAsPDF code
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

the code will search outlook sent folder by `[Subject]` so update to mach your Excel code `[Subject Title range]`

```
If olItem.Subject = [A1] Then ' Update cell [C218]
```

If subject found then call outlook script

```
SaveAsPDF olItem
```

*Remember to add - in VBE click TOOLS > REFERENCES and check the boxes for*

`Microsoft Outlook Object Library` & `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`

Comment: I am still trying to get this to work.  I have added my outlook script to the excel module that sends the email and made the changes as instructed.  I put `Option Explicit` code in its own module.  I run the first `sub` and the email is sent as expected.  Then I run the `Option Explicit` code and get "Compile Error: User-defined type not defined" with this line highlighted: `Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace`.  When I run the SaveAsPDF script on its own, I get same error on this line: `Sub SaveAsPDF(MyMail As MailItem)`

Comment: @ChrisM In VBE click TOOLS > REFERENCES and check the boxes for `microsoft outlook object library` & `microsoft scripting runtime`

Comment: I have the references checked.  still get the same error

Comment: @ChrisM try changing `Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem` to `Dim olItem As Object`

Comment: That did it!  But I had to remove `Debug.Print olItem`.  It produced an error method not supported, but it is working! Woo-Hoo!

Comment: No doubt!  Hit me up next time you're in Denver!

Comment: I added your Outlook sub to my original email sub so it executes automatically as soon as the email is sent (added a delay to let it finish sending).  Check out the final below!  All credit to you bro!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my final combined working code if anyone is interested (all in 1 module)

All props for combining code goes to Om3r who's got a frosty Colorado microbrew waiting for him!

This code will:

- Create a PDF of Active Worksheet, Attach it to Email
- After user sends email, searches Sent Mail folder for that email
- Saves a PDF copy of the sent email (and attachments if desired)

Sorry about the 'pre' format but ctrl+K wasn't cutting it! Scratch that, got it

```
Sub AttachActiveSheetPDF()
  Dim IsCreated As Boolean
  Dim PdfFile As String, Esub As String
  Dim OutlApp As Object
  Dim sendTime As String

    sendTime = Now()
    sendTime = Format(sendTime, "yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss")

  ' ### Define email subject and PDF path & filename ###
  Esub = sendTime & "_Completed Case Review"
  PdfFile = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\" & Esub & ".pdf"


  ' ### Export ActiveSheet to PDF ###
  With ActiveSheet
    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PdfFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
  End With

  ' ### Open Outlook ###
  On Error Resume Next
  Set OutlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")  '<-- If open, use it
  If Err Then
    Set OutlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")  '<-- If not, open it
    IsCreated = True
  End If
  OutlApp.Visible = True
  On Error GoTo 0

  ' ### Prepare email and attach pdf created above ###
  With OutlApp.CreateItem(0)

    .Subject = Esub
    .To = ""   ' <-- Put email of the recipient here
    .CC = ""
    .Body = "Hello," & vbLf & vbLf _
          & "Please find attached a completed case review." & vbLf & vbLf _
          & "Thank you," & vbLf _
          & Application.UserName & vbLf & vbLf
    .Attachments.Add PdfFile

    ' Try to send
    Application.Visible = True
    .Display True '<-- True forces code to wait for user to send email. Or just automate what the user is doing and change this to .Send
  End With

  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))  '<-- 5 second delay allows email to finish sending

' ### Search Sent Mail folder for emails with same timestamp in subject ###
    Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olItem As Object

    Set olNameSpace = OutlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = olNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
    Set olItem = OutlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    For Each olItem In olFolder.Items
        If olItem.Class = olMail Then
            If olItem.Subject = Esub Then  '<-- check for match
                SaveAsPDF olItem '< - Call SaveAsPDF code
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If IsCreated Then OutlApp.Quit  '<-- Quit Outlook if it was not already open
  Set OutlApp = Nothing  '<-- Release the memory of object variable

   ' ### Delete our temp pdf file if not needed anymore ###
  Kill PdfFile

End Sub


Sub SaveAsPDF(MyMail As MailItem)

' ### Requires reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime ###
' ### Requires reference to Microsoft Outlook Object Library ###
' ### Requires reference to Microsoft Word Object Library ###
' --- In VBE click TOOLS > REFERENCES and check the boxes for all of the above ---

  Dim fso As FileSystemObject
  Dim emailSubject As String
  Dim saveName As String
  Dim blnOverwrite As Boolean
  Dim bPath As String
  Dim strFolderPath As String
  Dim sendEmailAddr As String
  Dim senderName As String
  Dim looper As Integer
  Dim plooper As Integer
  Dim strID As String
  Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
  Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem

  strID = MyMail.EntryID
  Set App = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set olNS = App.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set oMail = olNS.GetItemFromID(strID)

  ' ### Get username portion of sender's email address ###
  sendEmailAddr = oMail.SenderEmailAddress
  senderName = Left(sendEmailAddr, InStr(sendEmailAddr, "@") - 1)

  ' ### USER OPTIONS ###
  blnOverwrite = False ' False = don't overwrite, True = do overwrite

  ' ### Path to directory for saving pdf copy of sent email ###
  bPath = "Z:\MyEmailFolder\"

  ' ### Create Directory if it doesnt exist ###
  If Dir(bPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
      MkDir bPath
  End If

  ' ### Get Email subject & set name to be saved as ###
  emailSubject = CleanFileName(oMail.Subject)
  saveName = emailSubject & ".mht"
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  ' ### Save .mht file to create pdf from within Word ###
  oMail.SaveAs bPath & saveName, olMHTML
  pdfSave = bPath & emailSubject & "_" & senderName & "_" & ".pdf"

  ' ### Open Word to convert .mht file to PDF ###
  Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
  Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
  Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

  ' ### Open .mht file we just saved and export as PDF ###
  Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=bPath & saveName, Visible:=True)
        wrdApp.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
                pdfSave, ExportFormat:= _
                wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
                wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=0, To:=0, _
                Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
                CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
                BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False

  wrdDoc.Close
  wrdApp.Quit

  ' ### Delete our temp .mht file ###
  Kill bPath & saveName

  ' ### Uncomment this section to save attachments also ###
  'If oMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
  '    For Each atmt In oMail.Attachments
  '        atmtName = CleanFileName(atmt.FileName)
  '        atmtSave = bPath & Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd-hhmm") & "_" & atmtName
  '        atmt.SaveAsFile atmtSave
  '    Next
  'End If

  Set oMail = Nothing
  Set olNS = Nothing
  Set fso = Nothing
End Sub


Function CleanFileName(strText As String) As String
Dim strStripChars As String
Dim intLen As Integer
Dim i As Integer
strStripChars = "/\[]:=," & Chr(34)
intLen = Len(strStripChars)
strText = Trim(strText)
For i = 1 To intLen
strText = Replace(strText, Mid(strStripChars, i, 1), "")
Next
CleanFileName = strText
End Function
```

Comment: well thankfully I was sooo proud of what I had done that I reviewed the whole post again and saw that the <pre> format was leaving out a huge chunk of code!  Got it now...I hope :-)